# find the number of characters in a line shell script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

So i need to create a one-liner command which gets as argument a pathway to a directory which contains anothers files and subdirectories.this files contain words separated by one blank or a comma or new line. The script must write in file "character" the total number of characters and in the file "character.err" will be written all the errors which may appear during the execution. Any idea? I tried with grep and tr and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) : (If I understand correctly)

```
$ cat file
foo,bar base
qux
$ awk -vRS='[ ,\n]' '{v+=length($0)}END{print FILENAME"="v " chars"}' file
file=13 chars
```

Comment: I need to count all the characters which are contain by all files in the directory.

Comment: it must be something like this:
find $1 -type f | cat | tr -d ",\n">>character.err | wc -c>character 2>>character.err
i'm not sure if the syntax is correct.....:))